# Is GTX 960 supported by Intel Chipset Q75?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

Intel chipset [Q75](http://ark.intel.com/products/64033/Intel-BD82Q75-PCH) supports PCI-e x1, x2 and x4. 
I have a similar problem as in the thread [What is the 6-pin power connector on an HP ProDesk?](https://superuser.com/q/869600/2005) but with *HP Compaq Pro 6300 Business PC*. 
I wanted to change its power supply to Corsair 750W but noticed it has the 6-pin fan power causing the problem so could not change the power supply.

PCI-e 2/3 is completely forward and backward compatible, [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2505121/nvidia-gtx-960-pci-express.html).
The motherboard should support GTX 960. 
I am confused.

Is GTX 960 supported by Intel Chipset Q75?

Comment: The chipset doesn't have to support the graphics card.

Comment: This is a reasonable question.  If you're going to downvote, state why.

Comment: The power supply does not have anything to do with the chipset,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your literal question, the [Q75 chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/64033/Intel-BD82Q75-PCH) does not support a GTX 960 card, at least not in any meaningful way.  The Q75 provides 8 PCIe lanes, but doesn't allow them to be grouped beyond x4, and x4 doesn't provide enough bandwidth for a card like a GTX 960.

In answer to the question you meant to ask, the lack of support doesn't matter.  Your mainboard's PCIe x16 slot isn't connected to the Q75, it's connected directly to the CPU, which provides 16 PCIe lanes that can be grouped at either x8 or x16, either of which will work with a GTX 960.

In answer to the question that really matters, you can't install a GTX 960 into a HP Compaq Pro 6300.  Although the mainboard and CPU support it, the power supply is nowhere near enough to handle it.  Further, since the computer uses an HP proprietary PSU, upgrading the power supply to something that *can* handle it is not practical.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the lanes directly to the CPU.  However, I think you may have overstated the problems with using an x4 slot... the GTX 960 may not be able to reach *peak* performance under *all* workloads, but it surely will perform well anyway, and in common scenarios where textures are stored in VRAM then it might not bottleneck on 4 lanes at all.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have an HP ProDesk 600 G1 and I am working on replacing the original HP custom power supply with an 500W ATX one (folowing the thread [What is the 6-pin power connector on an HP ProDesk?](https://superuser.com/questions/869600/what-is-the-6-pin-power-connector-on-an-hp-prodesk)) and fitting everything into a Fractal Design R4 case (done)

I bought an Asus GTX970 so since the lanes are connected to the CPU, I am hoping to play Witcher 3 and others in here ;)

I will post the schematics and pictures when I will finish it.