# What is the the best way to add a second power supply on an HP ProDesk?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I have ordered from http://www.add2psu.com/, i would like to add a second PSU to power a video card. The PSU with the HP is non standard and i do not want to make any mistakes. Any help wold be gratefully received.

I have the same computer as this:
[What is the 6-pin power connector on an HP ProDesk?](https://superuser.com/questions/869600/what-is-the-6-pin-power-connector-on-an-hp-prodesk?newreg=fe25b4f41e2f430aacff68be3f9e03cd)

Comment: I have a feeling that power supply is just going to be sitting next to your case, if the case wasn't designed to take a second PSU.  The part only has two plugs.  What are you going to mess up?

Comment: It will be but that wont be a problem. I work alone and the second psu will be safe on a shelf under the desk. When im not using it i will unplug it. As for the plugs, im new to this and dont want to screw something up by mistake. I am under the impression that some of the wires are non-standard despite the plugs being standard. I am happy to be taught otherwise. Also, thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: I assume you have a third party video card made by Nvidia or Ati, so how would the power plug on that not be standard ?

Comment: It woudl be best to look at this closely to understand my problem: https://superuser.com/questions/869600/what-is-the-6-pin-power-connector-on-an-hp-prodesk?newreg=fe25b4f41e2f430aacff68be3f9e03cd

Comment: i think ill try to use a four pin molex from the hard drive activate the "add2psu" and turn on my second psu.