# How turn on the HP power supply

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I had a problem on my HP computer.  My computer died and I believe that the problem is its power supply. The power supply is a PS-4241-9HA

My questions:

1. How to test or turn on the power supply when it is disconnected from the motherboard.
2. If it later turns out the power supply is broken, how do I (if I want to) replace it with another power supply which has a different connector (eg ATX 450W) because the OEM replacement is too expensive.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[3][3]

Comment: Bonz007, could you share your computer model number? Since this is a slim line power supply, you might not be able to fit a normal ATX supply in it.

Comment: @Bonz007,  as a new user, there's a limit on the number links you can include in the question, so #3 got dropped.  If you post that link in a comment, we can add it to the question for you.  If you "address" the comment to me with @, like I did here, I'll get an alert to your posting and will be happy to do it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, it is possible, but inadvisable to try to test this power supply. It is a proprietary wiring setup HP has engineered. The PSU provides only 12v to the motherboard, where it then converts the power and all devices  (hard drives, cd drives, fans, etc) connect to the motherboard directly. Simply put, part of what is in a normal PSU is actually in the motherboard itself. It looks like they even changed how the power on signal is sent from/to the motherboard, again, it might cause the power supply and/or you harm trying to even test this.

To answer your second question, it is VERY unlikely you would be able to fit any standard power supply in that case without some rigging, and even then, you would not be able to connect it to the motherboard without some rigging and adaptors. Also, since this power supply is often used in HP slim desktops, your case might not even be big enough for a standard power supply. Just buy an identical power supply (about $50US) and call it done.

Here is another discussion or replacing the power supply: [What is the 6-pin power connector on an HP ProDesk?](https://superuser.com/questions/869600/what-is-the-6-pin-power-connector-on-an-hp-prodesk)

Answer (score -2):

That is quite simple. To do that find the 24pin of your power supply.
Connect the GREEN wire with the adjacent BLACK wire and then plug it in.
When the Fan starts spinning, your Power Supply seems to be working.
If the Fan does not start spinning, your Power Supply is dead.

Comment: Not sure about this particular PS, but many require a load or they will shut down. You may need to place resistors across unused lines, if unplugged from load.

Comment: Simply connect a Hard Drive and you have enough load to run it.

Comment: The PSU connector is proprietary and would require an adaptor to match a standard ATX supply. Also, cable coloring might not match standard, etc. Please don't just throw standard answers out without looking into it first. You suggestion could ruin the supply or injure the user. Also, all devices are powered through the motherboard, so you can't simply connect a hard drive.